# Compostion of -schedule:(SEL)selector in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, composition, schedule

I have a spriteHandler object that composes (has) a CCSprite. It also composes a behavior object that has a method `-update:(ccTime)dt`, and a method `-updateSelector` that returns `@selector(update:)`. In the spriteHandler object, I want to use the method `-schedule:(SEL)selector`, implemented by CCSprite. The call `[sprite schedule:[behavior getUpdateSelector]]` fails; I can only figure out how to schedule something if you subclass CCNode. Is there any way to do this through composition?

Comment: What error are you getting when it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to run something just once or every frame? what do you mean, it fails?

In case `[sprite schedule:@selector(behaviourMethod)]` doesn't work try this instead:

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(behaviourMethod) forTarget:self interval:0.1 paused:NO];
```

Comment: I tried '[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(behaviourMethod) forTarget:self interval:0.1 paused:NO];' and it gave me an NSException. I tried setting 'behavior' as the target, and it worked (!), but my 'dt' that it's giving me in the '-update:(ccTime)dt' giving me bizzare values (negative numbers, absurdly high numbers, and mostly zeros). Am I screwing something up?

Comment: I think I'll count this one as answered, and ask the -update:(ccTime)dt question on a separate page. Thanks for the help!